# Redis setup for development environment

Tags: redis

I am new to Redis & I am in process of setting up a Redis OSS for development region for my project. I have few questions about the deployment model which I want to have validated.

1) Will Redis run on just one node? since my request is for a development region I do not need high availability.

2) Can I create multiple databases to support various projects with one instance I am setting up?

3) I am going with Red Hat Linux since for production I plan to use Redis Enterprise considering its support model.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes - the redis-server always runs on one node.

2) Yes - you can multiple logical/shared databases on the same server using the `SELECT` command. That, however, is considered bad practice. You should, instead, use a different redis-server for each database. These redis-server processes **CAN** be run on the same physical server.

3) You can use the trial version of the Enterprise for development.

Disclaimer: I work for Redis Labs, home of OSS Redis and provider of the Enterprise products line.

Answer (score 0):

Redis is designed to be single thread which has its own pros and cons. Redis answers for multi core with sharding - https://redis.io/topics/partitioning.

Yes you can create multiple databases in same redis instance though it is not recommended. But since you are setting up staging model its your call.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Redis proides three development models: single(default),sentinel,cluster. Without considering the model you used, you can just start the redis instance to build a test development.
2. If you want to support various projects with one instance, you can create a project for one database. Redis supports at most 16 databases. Also, you need do your logical work in Redis for the aimed project with con your destination database.
3. Redis is a free and opensource software, so it is unnecessary for you to consider if it is an enterprise, unless you buy a customized version from RedisLabs or other software company.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all ..

On creating multiple databases per http://www.rediscookbook.org/multiple_databases.html its mentioned that we can create multiple databases.

Since this is for development/ test region, I would think creating multiple databases should be fine compared with the production where we would need best performance.